# Storing website setting options with primay key as strign

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I am currently building a small social network for practice, really no big deal i just would like to learn more.

Wha i am stuck with is to store my website information options.

I checked other CMS database structures and saw most save these based on a primary key what is a string and that is the name

example

```
name           | option      |

site_name      | my site     |
site_desc      | awesome_site|
signup_enabled | 1           |
```

And i like how SocalEngine made it, they doing it this way

```
name                | option      |

core.site_name      | my site     |
core.site_desc      | awesome_site|
core.signup_enabled | 1           |
activity.limit      | 1           |
activity.enabled    | 1           |
activity.refresh    | 3000        |
```

As show above, they dentify the setting type before the dot. So `core.` are the core settings, and `activity.` os for activity settings, and this is what i am stuck witn

the `updating` part is not a problem, i know i need to select the specific primary keys loop through them passing the primary key back and update.

My problem is i am lost, how to make the `select query` and the `update query` to dentify  which name i am updating or selecting.

so what i mean example

**Core form**

```
"SELECT * FROM settings WHERE core."
```

**Activity form**

```
"SELECT * FROM settings WHERE activity."
```

**Updating**

```
UPDATE settings
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE core.=some_value;
```

So this is the par what i am stuck with, could please someone give me a hint with this, or some basic example? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all core options:

```
SELECT * FROM settings WHERE name like 'core.%'
```

Select a specific activity option:

```
SELECT * FROM settings WHERE name ='activity.enabled'
```

Update a specific core option:

```
UPDATE settings
SET option='new site name'
WHERE name = 'core.site_name';
```